# How can I determine the current event in Google Calendar using Python?

Tags: python, icalendar

I'm building a thermostat that pulls its target temperatures from a Google Calendar. In doing so, I need to determine the event happening now in said Google Calendar. At present, I'm fetching the .ics file from Google and then parsing it with [Python icalendar library](https://github.com/collective/icalendar).

I then iterate through every event in the calendar and test:

1. Is the event today?
2. Has the event started?
3. Has the event not ended?

After checking every event (assuming there are no overlapping events), I get one event where the answer is YES for all three questions. That's the current event.

Is there a better way to do this? In particular, is there any way to avoid iterating through every event in the calendar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use the [Google Calendar API](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/v3/getting_started.html). You can ask it for the events within a certain period of time, and it'll respond with some nice JSON that will give you the information. There's even a Python client that will take care of translating your requests to and from JSON.

There isn't a way of querying for the current event directly, but you can certainly give it a limited min and max time, so you'll only have a small number of events to search through. If your events are regular and of predictable duration, you may be able to make it just give you one.

```
events = client.events().list(calendarId='primary',
                              timeMin='2011-12-22T09:00:00Z',
                              timeMax='2011-12-22T22:00:00Z').execute()
```

Comment: That's a pretty good solution. I didn't realize the API had such capabilities. It does mean I'd have to implement caching of some sort for when the internet is not available. Maybe just sticking with the last available value would be reasonable.

Comment: what exactly is the 'client' object here? from which library?

Comment: From the Python client I mention, available at the link I gave.